# In Cartthrob, how could one stop a discount being applied with any other coupon?

Tags: cartthrob

We created a custom Cartthrob plugin which applies a 10% discount to items in the cart if purchased before a certain date, which works fine.

But we also have a coupon code to give 10% off.

Coupons and discounts are "not to be used with with any other offer". It means if someone enters the coupon code, the our custom discount should not be applied.

I can't find any help on this and wondered if anyone has a suggestion/solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have possibly found a solution, by retrieving the cart data direct from the database, decrypting and unserialising it I can obtain the cart data and see coupon codes applied, so am able to check against this.

```
private function _getCart($cart_id)
{
    $this->EE->load->library('encrypt');

    $query = ee()->db->select('cart')
        ->from('exp_cartthrob_cart ctc')
        ->where('ctc.id = "'.$cart_id.'"')
        ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $fields[] = '';
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $cart = unserialize($this->EE->encrypt->decode($row['cart']));
        }
    }

    return $cart;
}
```